# Chain rule for general derivative operator.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We have the derivative operator which is defined as:

$$D^{\alpha}f(x) : = \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)}{\partial^{\alpha_1}x_1\ldots \partial^{\alpha_n}x_n}$$

where $|\alpha | = \alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n $.

Now, how does the chain rule for $F\circ u$ look like?, i.e we have:

$$D^{\alpha}(F \circ u)(x_1,\ldots , x_n)$$

Comment: This is rather complicated. Just look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) for the chain rule for higher ordinary derivatives as an example.

Comment: How do I find the formula for partial derivatives?

Comment: Have you bothered to google for "faa di bruno partial derivatives" or something similar?

Comment: Yes, it does look complicated. I found this paper: http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/21265/3/FaadiBruno%20-%20copia.pdf